# Get amount of elements in a HashMap

Tags: rust

I would like to know how to get the amount of elements in a HashMap with rust.

I'm currently using this to check if a HashMap is empty or not, so if there is a more idiomatic way to get that as well, I would love to know both.

Comment: Did you read over [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::HashMap` has a [len](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.len) method to check for the number of elements, but you can use [is_empty](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.is_empty) method to check if it contains any items.

```
let mut map = HashMap::new();
assert!(map.is_empty());
assert_eq!(map.len(), 0);

a.insert(1, "a");
assert!(!map.is_empty());
assert_eq!(map.len(), 1);
```